# A-frame / other js lib, changing VR eye angles or eye camera position

Tags: javascript, aframe, virtual-reality, webvr, webxr

In VR mode of A-frame library, is it possible to change view angles for the eyes? I mean, set both eyes not to look at the same point but look at different items. I am aware of the fact that it may create a discomfort for the user.

Changing camera (eye) position (not angle) would be also be appreciated.

If A-frame is using WebXR api, I found that there is a property called XRView.projectionMatrix, however it's readonly. I'm looking for something similar but editable.

Comment: Ever since I first wore a VR headset some 20ish years ago I've wanted to try gecko eyes.